# EXCEL - Substract two 24hr time format cells with seconds and miliseconds

Tags: excel, time

Okay, so I have two cells:

```
Start           End
11:31:37.644    11:31:51.269
```

I'd like to subtract the two and return the remaining time which should equal something around 14 seconds.

Edit for more information:

My values I'm inputting are like so:

```
113137.644
113151.269
```

and I have a custom formatter set to: `00\:00\:00.000` to display what you see at the very top.

Comment: The problem is my value isn't 11:31:37.644, it's 113137.644 and is only being displayed as 11:31:37.644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `MID` function to grab each section of the time, like this:

```
=MID(A1,1,2)&":"&MID(A1,3,2)&":"&MID(A1,5,2)&"."&MID(A1,8,3)
```

This will change `113137.644` to `11:31:37.644`.

You can then do the math on it like this (all in one cell, but broken up here for readability):

```
=TEXT(MID(B1,1,2)&":"&MID(B1,3,2)&":"&MID(B1,5,2)&"."&MID(B1,8,3), "hh:mm:ss.000") 
 - 
 TEXT(MID(A1,1,2)&":"&MID(A1,3,2)&":"&MID(A1,5,2)&"."&MID(A1,8,3),"hh:mm:ss.000")
```

That should give you `0.000157697`.  Change the field's custom format to `hh:mm:ss.000` to give you `00:00:13.625`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you could input the values as real time values then you can just use a simple subtraction

`=A2-A1`

...but with the values as they are you can do a conversion and subtraction all in one using TEXT function, e.g. in A3 use this formula

`=TEXT(A2,"00\:00\:00.000")-TEXT(A1,"00\:00\:00.000")`

format A3 as [h]:mm:ss.000 to get **0:00:13.625** for your example

Assumes times are on the same "day", if you need to pass midnight you can revise formula to

`=MOD(TEXT(A2,"00\:00\:00.000")-TEXT(A1,"00\:00\:00.000"),1)`

Comment: I could have sworn I tried it with `TEXT(A2,"00\:00\:00.000")` but got an #VALUE error; I must have forgotten the slashes.  Anyways, nice clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to convert your values to time

```
=(LEFT(A1,2)+(MID(A1,3,2)+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)/60)/60)/24
```

You can then subtract and convert back using the following formula

```
=TEXT(B1,"hhmm")&TEXT(MOD(B1*24*60,1)*60,"00.000")
```

But it would probably be better for you to actually use proper decimal values in fractions of days or hours rather than this you can't calculate anything with.